# Save Page Forms' »unique number« into Semantic Mediawiki property

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

I use the Mediawiki Page Forms extension to create pages and set their names with a »page name« parameter like

`{{{info|page name=<My Template[Some property]>-<unique number;start=1>}}}`
(see [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms/Linking_to_forms#The_one-step_process) for details).

Is there a way to save that »unique number« into a Semantic MediaWiki property of the created page for later usage by SMW queries?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you have Extension:ParserFunctions installed

Add to your template:

```
{{#set:
|unique number={{#explode:{{PAGENAME}}|-|-1}} 
}}
```

*this explodes the page name on '-' and takes the last part*

See more on the PAGENAME magic word here:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Page_names

See more on the explode parser function here:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#explode